# What is the alternate of below sql in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, dateadd

Table '`Curcommtb`' has column '`DModify`' and '`Count`'

What is the alternate of below sql in SQLite?

'`select dateadd(day,count,DModify) from Curcommtb`'

Answer (score 5):

[SQLite date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Below is the SQLite alternate of your query.

```
SELECT date(DModify,'+'|| count||' day') FROm Curcommtb
```

You can use date function like:

```
SELECT date('now','+10 day');
```